# Реально ли сделать форму регистрации в WP со своими полями?

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть 2 плагина profile builder + Cimy User Extra Fields. Cimy User Extra Fields добавляет свои поля в регистрацию(стандартную). Как сделать что бы они попали в profile builde? Суть в том что мне нужна регистрация в всплывающем окне со своими полями. Пока никак не получается.

Answer (score 2):

Можно упростить твою задачу. Всплывающее окно можно сделать своими средствами и добавить поля, дописав немного кода.

Я использую bootstrap (но можешь поискать и другие варианты в интернете как сделать всплывающую форму). Если будешь использовать бутстрап, подключи его css и js.

Всплывающая форма:

```
<?php if (is_user_logged_in()): ?>
    <p><a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( home_url() ); ?>">Выйти</a></p>
<?php endif ?>
<?php if (!(is_user_logged_in())): ?>
    <p><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="http://4eizmerenie.ru/wp-login.php">Войти</a></p>
<?php endif ?>
```

Ниже сам код формы:

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

(взято отсюда: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

Теперь что касается дополнительных полей:
в самой документации WP написано как добавить (код вполне рабочий):
https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Registration_Form

Т.е. добавить в файл funtions.php (ну исправив на нужное название полей):

```
//1. Add a new form element...
add_action( 'register_form', 'myplugin_register_form' );
function myplugin_register_form() {

$first_name = ( ! empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) ) ? trim( $_POST['first_name'] ) : '';

    ?>
    <p>
        <label for="first_name"><?php _e( 'First Name', 'mydomain' ) ?><br />
            <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="input" value="<?php echo esc_attr( wp_unslash( $first_name ) ); ?>" size="25" /></label>
    </p>
    <?php
}

//2. Add validation. In this case, we make sure first_name is required.
add_filter( 'registration_errors', 'myplugin_registration_errors', 10, 3 );
function myplugin_registration_errors( $errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email ) {

    if ( empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) || ! empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) && trim( $_POST['first_name'] ) == '' ) {
        $errors->add( 'first_name_error', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: You must include a first name.', 'mydomain' ) );
    }

    return $errors;
}

//3. Finally, save our extra registration user meta.
add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_user_register' );
function myplugin_user_register( $user_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'first_name', trim( $_POST['first_name'] ) );
    }
}
```